# Spark Scala program only prints first line in Google Dataproc

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, google-cloud-dataproc

I have used SBT to build a jar file, and have tried to expand beyond the "Hello, world!" first code on Google Dataproc. When I submit the job, it only prints the first "Hello, world!" and does not print the reduce of the rdd (should be 30) nor the "...after...". Of course, these three println work correctly if I run on spark-shell on my laptop. Any pointers would be great, I can't seem to find out what Google Dataproc is looking for.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}

object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
    val sc = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate().sparkContext
    val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(5, 10, 15))
    println(rdd.reduce(_+_))
    println("...after...")
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's needed, but my build.sbt file is below:

```
name := "HelloWorld"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.3"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.1"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.0.1"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-graphx
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "3.0.1"
artifactName := { (sv: ScalaVersion, module: ModuleID, artifact: Artifact) => "HelloWorld.jar" }
```

Answer (score 1):

what is the default cluster manager in google data proc?

you can remove master("local") from your code and run, so it will run on default cluster manager, when you don't supply any arguments during spark-submit.

```
val sc = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate().sparkContext
```

Comment: I am following this guide on Google Dataproc https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/spark-scala#use_sbt. When I delete the master("local) as noted above, and then do the "run" command as outlined in the guide, I get the error "org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration".

Comment: I just re-setup my cluster and I don't see an entry for "default cluster manager"? Could you provide some description so I can find out what this it is set to?

Comment: Just to clarify my first comment, I am following the sections of the guide for sbt on my laptop to generate the .jar file.

Comment: Karthik, apologize for this. I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing today differently than yesterday, but now I am seeing the output "30" and "...after...". I've compiled and packaged the code, uploaded to gcs, and submitted jobs twice, and it is now working consistently.

Comment: Did you re-create the cluster? I wonder if some older versioned image had some issue. I tried your code on a Dataproc 2.0 cluster with all default settings, and it ran just fine. One thing though, is that the "Hello World" message prints before the creation of the Spark context, so it appears first but there are more logging entries before "30" and "...after..." are printed so maybe you missed those because of the extra entries in the first place?